# Java data structure that sorts and groups by Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, grouping, comparator

Is there a Java data structure that will sort and group by a provided Comparator instance?
Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
Input: [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3]
Output: [[1,1], [2], [3,3], [4,4], [5]] // sorted, all occurrences of "equal" elements preserved
```

The closest I could find is TreeMultiset or TreeBag - but these do not preserve each occurrence of an element, only one element and the number of its occurrences.

Here is another example:

```
List<Book> books = [
      {author: "1", title: "Book1", ...}, 
      {author: "1", title: "Book2", ...},
      {author: "0", title: "Book0", ...} ... ];

UnknownDataStructure<Book> booksByAuthor = new UnknownDataStructure<Book>(Comparator.comparing(Book::author));
booksByAuthor.addAll(books);

booksByAuthor then should be equivalent to: [
      [{author: "0", title: "Book0", ...}]
      [{author: "1", title: "Book1", ...}, {author: "1", title: "Book2", ...}],
       ... ];
```

For my particular use case the `Comparator` instance is configurable - it could be by any sub-set of the `Book` POJO fields (each with its own sort direction and nullsFirst/nullsLast specifier), for example: `Comparator.comparing(Book:author).thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Book::title))...`

The key requirement is that the list of `Book`s should be sorted and grouped, with each group containing all `Book`s that are equivalent (in the sense that `Comparator.compareTo(book1, book2)` is `0` for any `book1/book2` from the group)

One option that I tried is to create another POJO like this:

```
public record SortKey(List<Comparable> values) { }
```

`SortKey` instance is created for each Book POJO and holds the Comparable values that we need to sort by (author, title, rating etc). Then I can just create a `TreeMap<SortKey, List<Book>>` instance and group by `SortKey`.

This looks cumbersome and the `SortKey` instances are only ever used as keys in the `TreeMap`, not needed for anything else. I am wondering whether I can just supply a `Comparator` instance and avoid using `SortKey`s.

Comment: Essentially you're looking for `Collectors.groupingBy`

Comment: To my knowledge - not really, at least `Collectors.groupingBy` in the current form does not support this use case (without using `SortKey`s)

Comment: Not quite sure why this doesn't fit the 'Book' requirement in that case: `import java.util.*;import java.util.stream.*;public class BookGroups {public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {record Book (String author, String title) {};Book[] books = {new Book("1", "Book1"),new Book("2", "Book2 by 2"),new Book("1", "Book3 by 1")};Map<String, List<Book>> m = Arrays.stream(books).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(b -> b.author));System.out.println(m);}}`

Comment: You can create your own data structures.  In the first example, you would use a two-dimensional `int` array.  In the second example, you create an `Author` class that includes a `List<Book>`.  Even if there was some generic grouping structure, like a `Map`, creating custom classes helps your code to be self-documenting.

Comment: The issue is that the list of fields I need to sort and group by is dynamic and each field has additional properties like `nullsFirst/nullsLast` and `asc/desc` (imagine a table widget that displays Books and a user requesting to sort them by multiple columns, and expecting similar rows to be grouped and highlighted in the same color)